# Mobile switch more than is mobile is not mobile

Tags: views, panels, theming

D7
I am using mobile switch with panels to display different views for different devices, but the only options I see are is mobile or is not mobile. On bigger devices like tablets I would like to display something other than what I would show on mobile phone. Is there any way I can get more option in mobile switch?

Answer (score 0):

People on tablets prefer to browse the Desktop version.

From this page: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/tablets:

> If your website has different pages to serve desktop and smartphone
>   users and does not have tablet-specific pages, **in our experience
>   tablet users usually expect to see your desktop site rather than the
>   site's smartphone pages**.

Mobile switch does not work with caching on.

So I'm using the php code from this site:  http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Also see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/javascript-solution-to-detect-mobile-browser.

So if you want more control, you need to write your own module giving the flexibility you need.

Answer (score 0):

The [Mobile Detect](https://drupal.org/project/mobile_detect) module has a ctool submodule that provides a selection plugin.

If you install/enable the module, you can add a **Selection** rule for your panel variant, and then choose device types.

The two basic ones are isMobile and isTablet, and you will also get all of the additional rules that your version of Mobile_Detect.php provides.  The project page and README have more information.

Disclosure: I am the author of Mobile Detect.